# Android periodic WorkManager not working with large intervals

Tags: android

I'm developing a feature that needs to be fired one day per week, with no exact time, for that i'm using WorkManager's periodic work as recommended by Google. The problem is that if the interval is too big, `doWork` method is not called, even though at the time of the execution i can log stuff on the application level, meaning that the work was triggered correctly but `doWork` was'nt called. What i have so far:

```
private fun initMissingDAWorker() {


    val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MissingDANotificationWorker>(
        ONE_WEEK_PERIODICITY,
        TimeUnit.DAYS,
        15,
        TimeUnit.MINUTES
    ).setInitialDelay(defineTimeAndInitialDelay(mStoredWeekDay!!, mStoredHour!!), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // This just set a default delay.
     .build()


    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        MISSING_DA_UNIQUE_WORK_NAME,
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        workRequest
    )
}
```

And the Worker class:

```
class MissingDANotificationWorker(private val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

    return try {

        MissingDANotificationUtil.buildAndSendNotification(context)

        Result.success()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Result.retry()
    }
}}
```

Interval time is set to 7 days, but when the time comes, the Worker class doesn't do what it should do, but the application logs are fired anyway...but when i set the interval time to something like 15 minutes, it works fine, so what is the problem here?

Comment: What's the value of `ONE_WEEK_PERIODICITY`?

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel 7, with time unit set to days (1 week)